# How do i connect ZOHO CRM with Zapier using php code?

Tags: integration, zapier, zoho

Is there any PHP library or code for ZAPIER that connect ZOHO to with my website (core php)?
I want to use PHP script to connect ZOHO with my website (having form) using ZAPIER.
Will any one please guide me or provide some reference link on how to achieve this.?

Answer (score 2):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

I'm not sure which ZOHO product you're using, but we connect with [a](https://zapier.com/zapbook/zoho-crm/) [lot](https://zapier.com/zapbook/zoho-creator/) [of](https://zapier.com/zapbook/zoho-projects/) [them](https://zapier.com/zapbook/zoho-recruit/).

As for PHP, Zapier connects to other services primarily via webhooks. There's an example of doing that with PHP here: https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_ajax_php.asp. On the Zapier side, you'd create a zap with a "Catch a Webhook" trigger and connect it to whatever you'd like.